# There's something wrong with my JDBC, but I don't know why

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

My MySQL JDBC doesn't run. I setup a MySQL database and tried to borrow books from it, but the program terminated before I typed `card_ number`. But there is a console output with a stack trace.

Stack trace:

> java.sql.SQLException: Illegal operation on empty result set.

My JDBC class:

```
package dblab;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

public class dblab5 {

    static Connection conn;

    public static void main(String args[]){

        start("root","991108");
    }

    public static void start(String userid, String passwd) { 
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lab5?"
                + "user=root&password=991108&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF8&serverTimezone=GMT";

        try{ 
            Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

            System.out.println("********************************************************");
            System.out.println("\t\t\t图书管理系统");
            System.out.println("********************************************************");

            Scanner reader=new Scanner(System.in);

            while(true){
            System.out.println("1.图书查询 2.借书 3.还书 4.图书入库 5.借阅证管理 0.退出系统");
            System.out.println("请输入需要的服务编号:");
            int choice=reader.nextInt();
            switch(choice)
            {
                case 0 :
                    conn.close();
                    return;
                case 1:
                    check_Book();
                    break;
                case 2 :
                    borrow_Book();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    return_Book();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    add_Book();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    proof_Manag();
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("服务编号错误");
            }
            }
        }catch (Exception sqle){ 
            System.out.println("Exception : " + sqle);
        }
    }

    static void check_Book() throws SQLException
    {
        String query;//查询语句
        int choice=0;//存放用户选项

        Scanner reader=new Scanner(System.in);

        while(true){
        System.out.println("1.查询全部 2.按书名查询 3.按书号查询 0.退出");
        System.out.println("请输入需要的服务编号");
        choice=reader.nextInt();
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 0 :
                return;
            case 1:
                //执行SQL语句
                query="SELECT * FROM book";

                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();        
                ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(query);

                System.out.println("查询结果如下");
                System.out.println("********************************************************************************");
                System.out.println("书号\t类别\t书名\t出版社\t年份\t作者\t价格\t总藏书量\t库存");
                System.out.println("********************************************************************************");

                while (rset.next()) { 
                    System.out.println(rset.getString("bno")+"\t"+rset.getString("category")+
                            "\t"+rset.getString("title")+"\t"+rset.getString("press")+
                            "\t"+rset.getInt("year")+"\t"+rset.getString("author")+
                            "\t"+rset.getDouble("price")+"\t"+rset.getInt("total")+"\t"+rset.getInt("stock"));

                }
                stmt.close();

                break;  
            default:
                System.out.println("服务编号错误");

        }
        }
    }
    static void borrow_Book() throws SQLException
    {
        String query;//查询语句
        int choice=0;//存放用户选项

        Scanner reader=new Scanner(System.in);

        while(true){
        System.out.println("1.继续借书 0.退出");
        System.out.println("请输入需要的服务编号");
        choice=reader.nextInt();
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 0 :
                return;
            default:
                System.out.println("请输入书名及借阅证编号");
                String bookname=reader.nextLine();
                String card_number=reader.nextLine();
                //执行SQL语句
                query="SELECT bno FROM borrow WHERE cno='"+card_number+"'";
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(query);

                System.out.println("已借出");
                System.out.println("********************************************************************************");
                System.out.println("书号");
                System.out.println("********************************************************************************");
                while (rset.next()) { 
                    System.out.println(rset.getString("bno"));
                }
                query="SELECT* FROM book WHERE title='"+bookname+"'";
                rset = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                int stock=rset.getInt("stock");
                System.out.println(stock);
                if(stock>0){
                    stock--;
                    query="UPDATE TABLE book SET stock=? WHERE bno=?";
                    try{
                    PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(query);
                    ps.setInt(1,stock);
                    ps.setString(2,bookname);
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                    }
                    catch (SQLException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    query="SELECT *FROM book WHERE title='"+bookname+"'";
                    rset=stmt.executeQuery(query);
                    String bookid=rset.getString("bno");
                    query="INSERT INTO borrow VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
                    try{
                    PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(query);
                    ps.setString(1,card_number);
                    ps.setString(2,bookid);
                    System.out.println("请输入当前日期");
                    int date =reader.nextInt();
                    ps.setInt(3,date);
                    //ps.setInt(4,null);
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                }
                catch (SQLException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                    System.out.println("借书成功");
                }

                if(stock==0){
                    System.out.println("库存不足");
                    rset=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT max(return_date) FROM borrow");
                    int date =rset.getInt("return_date");
                    System.out.println("最近归还日期为"+date);
                }

                stmt.close();
                break;
        }
        }
    }
    static void return_Book() throws SQLException
    {
        String query;//查询语句
        int choice=0;//存放用户选项

        Scanner reader=new Scanner(System.in);

        while(true){
        System.out.println("1.继续还书 0.退出");
        System.out.println("请输入需要的服务编号");
        choice=reader.nextInt();
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 0 :
                return;
            default:
                System.out.println("请输入书名及借阅证编号");
                String bookname=reader.nextLine();
                String card_number=reader.nextLine();
                //执行SQL语句
                query="SELECT bno FROM borrow WHERE return_date=null";
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();        
                ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                System.out.println("已借出");
                System.out.println("********************************************************************************");
                System.out.println("书号");
                System.out.println("********************************************************************************");
                while (rset.next()) { 
                    System.out.println(rset.getString("bno"));
                }

                query="SELECT stock FROM book WHERE title='"+bookname+"'^cno='"+card_number+"'";
                rset = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                if(rset.wasNull())
                System.out.println("数据错误");
                else{
                    query="SELECT *FROM book WHERE title='"+bookname+"'";
                    rset = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                    int stock=rset.getInt("stock");
                    System.out.println("请输入当前日期");
                    int date=reader.nextInt();
                    query="UPDATE TABLE book SET stock=? WHERE bno=?";
                    try{
                    PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(query);
                    ps.setInt(1,stock);
                    ps.setString(2,bookname);
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                    }
                    catch (SQLException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    query="UPDATE TABLE borrow SET return_date=? WHERE title=?^cno=?";
                    try{
                    PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(query);
                    ps.setInt(1,date);
                    ps.setString(2,bookname);
                    ps.setString(3,card_number);
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                    }
                    catch (SQLException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println("还书成功");
                }
                stmt.close();
                break;
        }
        }
    }
    static void add_Book() throws SQLException
    {
        String query;//查询语句
        int choice=0;//存放用户选项

        Scanner reader=new Scanner(System.in);

        while(true){
        System.out.println("1.单本入库 2.批量入库 0.退出");
        System.out.println("请输入需要的服务编号");
        choice=reader.nextInt();
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 0 :
                return;
            case 1:
                System.out.println("请输入书号,书名,作者,出版社,价格,类别,年份(0退出系统)");
                //书号, 类别, 书名, 出版社, 年份, 作者, 价格, 总藏书量, 库存
                String bno_in=reader.nextLine();
                String title_in=reader.nextLine();
                String author_in=reader.nextLine();
                String press_in=reader.nextLine();
                float price_in=reader.nextFloat();
                String category_in=reader.nextLine();
                int year_in=reader.nextInt();
                //执行SQL语句
                query="SELECT *FROM book WHERE bno='"+bno_in+"'";
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                int total=rset.getInt("total");
                int stock=rset.getInt("stock");
                query="INSERT INTO book VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                try{
                    PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(query);
                    ps.setString(1,bno_in);
                    ps.setString(2,category_in);
                    ps.setString(3,title_in);
                    ps.setString(4,press_in);
                    ps.setInt(5,year_in);
                    ps.setString(6,author_in);
                    ps.setFloat(7,price_in);
                    ps.setInt(8,total+1);
                    ps.setInt(9,stock+1);
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                }
                catch (SQLException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                stmt.close();
                break;
            case 2:
                 System.out.println("请输入路径");

            default:
                System.out.println("服务编号错误");
        }
        }
    }
    static void proof_Manag() throws SQLException
    {
        String query;//查询语句
        int choice=0;//存放用户选项

        Scanner reader=new Scanner(System.in);

        while(true){
        System.out.println("1.删除借阅证 2.增加借阅证 3.借阅证修改 0.退出系统");
        System.out.println("请输入需要的服务编号");
        choice=reader.nextInt();
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 0 :
                return;
            case 1:
                //删除借阅证
                System.out.println("请输入卡号");
                String cno_in=reader.nextLine();
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();        
                query="DELETE FROM card WHERE cno=?";
                try{
                    PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(query);
                    ps.setString(1,cno_in);
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                }
                catch (SQLException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                stmt.close();
                break;
            case 2:
            //增加借阅证
                System.out.println("请输入借阅证信息");
                System.out.println("卡号\t姓名\t单位\t类别");
                Statement stmt2 = conn.createStatement();
                String cno_in2=reader.nextLine();
                String name_in2=reader.nextLine();
                String dept_in2=reader.nextLine();
                String type_in2=reader.nextLine();
                query="INSERT INTO card VALUES(?,?,?)";//cno,name,department
                try{
                    PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(query);
                    ps.setString(1,cno_in2);
                    ps.setString(2,name_in2);
                    ps.setString(3,dept_in2);
                    ps.setString(4,type_in2);
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                }
                catch (SQLException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                stmt2.close();
                break;
            case 3:
            //修改借阅证
                Statement stmt3 = conn.createStatement();
                System.out.println("请输入借阅证信息");
                System.out.println("卡号\t姓名\t单位\t类别");
                String cno_in3=reader.nextLine();
                String name_in3=reader.nextLine();
                String dept_in3=reader.nextLine();
                String type_in3=reader.nextLine();
                query="UPDATE TABLE card SET name='"+name_in3+
                "',department='"+dept_in3+"',type='"+type_in3+"' WHERE cno="+cno_in3;
                try{
                    PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(query);
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                }
                catch (SQLException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                stmt3.close();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("服务编号错误");
        }   
        }
    }
}
```

Why does this empty result set appear?

Comment: Please post full stack trace.

Comment: And remove any code that is not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `ResultSet` without invoking `next()`

That pattern in your code is wrong:

```
query="SELECT* FROM book WHERE title='"+bookname+"'";
rset = stmt.executeQuery(query);
int stock=rset.getInt("stock");
```

You need to execute `rset.next()` probably as a loop condition and get your field values after the call to `next()`.

Comment: Thank you very much. My program is running normally now！

Answer (score 0):

You should address the following things in your code:

1. Use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) instead of `Statement` in case of parametrized query to avoid [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Apart from preventing the possibility of SQL injection, it also helps you get rid of using `''` explicitly as you have done in `query="SELECT bno FROM borrow WHERE cno='"+card_number+"'";`.

```
query="SELECT bno FROM borrow WHERE cno=?";
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
pstmt.setString(1, card_number);
ResultSet rset = pstmt.executeQuery();
While(rset.next()) {
    //...
}
```

2. Do not use `Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`. It is not needed since JDBC 4.0.
3. Make sure to check `rset.next()` before trying to access any data from `rset` as shown in the code above. You have missed this check in the following code:

```
query="SELECT* FROM book WHERE title='"+bookname+"'";
rset = stmt.executeQuery(query);
int stock=rset.getInt("stock");
```

Comment: Thank you！ Your advice has helped me a lot